# Windows 7 fails to connect connect to samba

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, samba

I have a local workgroup network.

It has one ubuntu 10 LTS machine, two XP boxes and a Windows 7.

I everything works great except for the Windows 7 box. I can see it and access it from the other boxes, including the Ubuntu one.

From the W7 i can access the XP's and I can see the Ubuntu machine, but if i try to Map Network Drive it fails to authenticate the user (i can use that user/psw from a different box).

[EDIT]
Windows 7 Home Premium seems to be missing the **Local Security Policy** editor

Comment: What version of samba?

Comment: @uSlackr: i commanded `sudo apt-get install samba smbfs` which I assumed would install the latest version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i have it working now.

I had previously changed the settings under **config advanced sharing** (translated from spanish, so not sure) I activated network detection, shared use of documents and printers, deactivated password protected shared use, and changed 128-bit encryption to 40/56 bits.

Now, before I had Windows administering the connections, so I changed that to use user and password to connect instead and works...

Sorry if the option names don't correlate literally to the english names, I have the OS in Spanish. Hard to translate.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Homegroup is turned off on the Win7 machine. Homegroup only really works in pure Win7/Homegroup environments (or, at the very least, when networking only Win7 machines is what matters), and can cause problems in mixed environments.

Second, make sure you've installed Samba **server** (not just the client), and have set up a Samba user for the Windows machines to use. The Samba user is different from the computer user and only a Samba user will be allowed to access the shares.

If you still have trouble, you might want to check out [a Google search](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=networking%20windows%20and%20ubuntu%20with%20samba) on the topic, as Win7 doesn't always like to play well with Samba.

Comment: I'm thinking that samba works ok since I had no troubles when the network was only ubuntu+XP, the issue was when I added the W7 box so I believe it is a specific issue with that OS version.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with this depending on the version and settings of Samba.  Windows 7 defaults to NTLM responses only.  You can change it to send LM and NTLM.  [Details here](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/75-63-windows-samba-issue#t1444)

There should be a corresponding for the samba server side, but I cannot find it off-hand.  But the above should cure your ills.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had found that thread on my google search, but had issues following the steps (can't find the **Local Security Policy** tool

Comment: @goliatone - Make sure you have Advanced File Sharing turned on, then. It's likely that information is hiding if you only have basic sharing on.

Comment: try running gpedit.msc from the start menu search box